# Estimate the value of $D$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, transformation

**Q**: In the figure below the graph of $f(x)$ is given in solid blue line; the graph of $g(x)=Af(Bx+C)+D$ is in dotted red line.

[image]

Estimate the value of $D$.
my try:
I know this,
$$Q(x, y)\longrightarrow Q'\left(\frac{x-C}{B}, A.y+D\right)$$
so
$$A(-3, -4)\longrightarrow A'(-12, -1)$$
$$B(10, 1)\longrightarrow B'(1, 14)$$
$$-4A+D=-1, \ \ A+D=14$$
solve the system of equations
$$(A,D)=(3, 11)$$
but the answer is $D=2.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is $Q$ coming from?

Comment: Your determination of point correspondence is wrong. You can use the fact that value $f(x)$ in one extremum is between $f(-\infty)$ and $f(\infty)$. Then point $(5,-2)$ goes to $(-7,8)$ and $(1,2)$ goes to $(3,-4)$. Then $2A+D=-4$, $-2A+D=8$. Adding gives $2D=4$, $D=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we notice that $A$ is negative since the function is flipped about the $y-$ axis before being shifted further. We notice that because in $f(x)$ the left horizontal is the absolute minimum while in $g(x)$ the right horizontal is the absolute maximum.

Next we look at the constant parts (horizontal) of the functions to find $A$ and $D$. We concentrate on the areas where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively constant to avoid having to deal with $B$ and $C$

We notice that $f(x)=-4$ corresponds with $g(x)=14$ and $f(x)=1$ corresponds with $g(x)=-1$. This leads us to the system of equation
$$\begin{cases}
14=A(-4)+D\\
-1=A(1)+D
\end{cases}$$

With a solution of $A=-3$ and $D=2$

Comment: Thanks for everything sir.

Comment: @Adzetto anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Start by looking at the asymptotic behaviour $x\to\pm\infty$ of both functions $f$ and $g$. What can you deduce about the unknown coefficients? Then look at the zeros of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for everything sir.